# Parse value from jquery to php and truncate mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Please I am a newbie to Jquery and javascript however I am trying to parse a table name from jquery to a php page which which will be used to truncate a table.
Please below is what I have tried so far...

Jquery page

```
$(function() {
    $.winFocus(function(event, isVisible) {
        if(isVisible){
            var tableName="table1";

            $("#isVisible").val(tableName);
        }
        else {
            var tableName = "table2";
            $("#isVisible").val("tableName");
        }
    });
})
```

The PHP form

```
 //table name value from jquery
$tableName ='<div id="tableName"></div>';

// mysql query that truncates the table
$query = "TRUNCATE TABLE $tableName";
```

This does not give any error,yet it doesnt truncate the table. Please what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

try this code to delete data from your table

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("$btnID").click(function(){
$.post("deletePageName.php",{"tableName":'myTable'},function(data){
alert(data);
})
});

});
```

on php Page

```
<?
$tableName=$_POST["tableName"];
mysql_query("delete from ".$tableName);
echo "data clear";
?>
```

thank you